# Как вставить в переменную twig кусок кода из php переменной?

Tags: php, html, twig, slim

я использую  версию php 7.4.16,  slim 4 и twig ^3.2 для создания блога.
Проблема заключается в том что моя перремнная вставляется как строка, а не как часть разметки html

[image: проблема]

```
Структура проетка

>  templates:
>          base.twig
>          home.twig 
>  index.php
```

содержимое home.twig

```
<div> Lorem <div>
```

содержимое base.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> {{ title }} </title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ content }}
</body>
</html>
```

В index.php я выполняю код

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) use($view) {
    $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('templates');
    $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
        'cache' => 'cache',
    ]);
  

    $home =  file_get_contents ('templates/home.twig'); // получаю содержимое из home.twig
    
    echo $twig->render('base.twig', ['title' => 'home', 'content' => $home ]); // тут я вставляю в перемнную content содержимое $home       
    return $response;
});




$app->run();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Твиг по умолчанию экранирует все данные при выводе. Чтобы выводить данные как есть, используй фильтр `raw`:

```
<body>
    {{ content|raw }}
</body>
```

Экранирование по умолчанию нужно, чтобы некоторые не жаловались, что у них возникает какой-нибудь XSS из-за твига.

Дополнительно можно [установить в `false` опцию `autoescape`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#environment-options) при создании объекта класса `Environment`, но это опять же **небезопасно**, так как в этом случае вообще все выводимые переменные будут выводиться как есть, что повышает шансы XSS.

Comment: А есть ли другое решение данной проблемы ? В моем случае данный метод все также выводит результат, как на изображение выше.

Comment: Все должно работать, возможно надо очистить твиговый кеш.

Comment: Да, все верно, проблема оказалась в кеше. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: Обновил ответ с настройкой для инстанса `Environment`.

Answer (score 1):

Twig поддерживает layout'ы - это то, что вам нужно

`base.twig` перепишите так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> {{ title }} </title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

`home.twig` так:

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}

{% block content %}
<div> Lorem <div>
{% endblock %}
```

И `index.php` так:

```php
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('templates');
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
    'cache' => 'cache',
]);

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) use($twig) {
    // лучше получать объект twig через зависимости, но это уже другая тема

    $response->getBody()->write($twig->render('home.twig', [
        'title' => 'home',
    ]));
    return $response;
});




$app->run();
```

Comment: спасибо большое за информацию)